# Creating lots of dictionaries from a list of names

Tags: python

I am making a times table/ division game where I have created dictionaries for each times table and division (up to 12) made up of the question as the key and answer as the value. That is 24 dictionaries! There is surely a better way of doing this than what I have done, perhaps creating a for loop.

I have managed to make each times table/ division dictionary using the following loop code (24 times; 12 for the multiple tables and 12 for the division equivalents) I have included an example of a multiple dictionary as well as a division one.

```
eleven_division = {}
for i in range (0,13):
    division_factor = 11 
    answer = i * division_factor
    eleven_division ['{} / {} ='.format(answer,division_factor)] = i

six_times = {}
for i in range (0,13):
    multiple = 6
    answer = i * multiple
    six_times ['{} x {} ='.format(i,multiple)] = answer
```

I would like to create all the dictionaries using nested for loops, but have each dictionary named in the following way: two_times, three_times, four_times. However, I can figure out a way to do this.

I know I can do this to print out all the division tables.

```
for x in range (1,13):
    division_factor = x
    for i in range (0,13):
        answer = i * division_factor
        print ('%s / %s = %s' %(answer, x, i))
```

I now need to create a new dictionary every time is goes through the loop so I thought the following might do it, but no!

```
    dicts =['one division', 'two division','three division','four division', 'five division', 'six division', 'seven division', 'eight division', 'nine division', 'ten division', 'eleven division', 'twelve division']
for f in dicts:
    f = {} 
    for x in range (1,13):
        division_factor = x
        for i in range (0,13):
            answer = i * division_factor
            f ['{} x {} ='.format(answer,x)] = i

print (one division) #THIS IS THE BIT I WANT WORKING!
```

I hope I have made my issue clear enough for you.

TIA!

Comment: You don’t want 12 separate variables, each holding a dict. Instead, you want one dict of dicts, or one list of dicts, or even just one dict using pairs of numbers instead of just numbers as the keys.

Comment: Are you able to provide me with the syntax for creating a dict of dicts. I did think of that but again I couldn't code it and I wouldn't know how to access each one. Thank you

Comment: Here is a simple example of dicts in a dict:  `dict_of_dicts = {"DICT1":{"SUB_DICT:"DATA"}, "DICT2:{"SUB_DICT:"DATA"}}`

Comment: actually i may may need 12 dicts because my game has different levels which contain different times table questions. For each level, I create a dict of the dicts involved in that level and then remove any duplicates to ensure a variety of questions. I'm not sure whether this changes the solution you propose

Comment: Think of the first level dict as a list of all your levels. then the sub dict as the level itself. Then if you need a sub to the sub for each question within the level you can do that as well. `dict_of_dicts = {"LVL1":{"QUESTION1":"some question?, "ANSWERS:[1, 2, 3], "CorrectAnswer:2}}` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem, you’ve got 12 separate division dicts, and you don’t know how to do anything with them without some horrible code like this:

```
if i==1: table = one_division
elif i==2: table = two_division
# … 10 more lines of code
do_something_with(table)
```

The answer is that you don’t want those dicts in 12 separate variables, you want them in a dict, so you can just look them up like this:

```
do_something_with(division_tables[i])
```

One line instead of 13, and easier to understand, too.

You can generate this dict in a loop:

```
division_tables = {}
for division_factor in range(1, 13):
    table = {}
    for i in range (0,13):
        answer = i * division_factor
        table['{} / {} ='.format(answer,division_factor)] = i
    division_tables[division_factor] = table
```

And now you can write a game like this:

```
factor = random.choide(division_tables)
table = division_tables[factor]
question = random.choice(table)
answer = table[question]
guess = int(input(question))
if guess == answer:
    print('You are correct, sir!')
else:
    print('Hahahaha, a 20-line Python script has outsmarted you’')
```

---

If you want these dicts in a useful order, so you can choose an easy question by picking, say, one of the first three tables, then you probably want a list rather than a dict:

```
division_tables = []
for division_factor in range(1, 13):
    table = {}
    for i in range (0,13):
        answer = i * division_factor
        table['{} / {} ='.format(answer,division_factor)] = i
    division_tables.append(table)
```

And now you can just do:

```
print('Easy question first:')
table = random.choice(division_tables[:3])
# … the rest of the code is the same as before
```

Comment: Incredible and so elegant! You've helped me so much! I can now delete about 100 lines of code!